# Pinning a Program to Taskbar Through Command Line in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe, taskbar

Title says it all. I'm working on a build to push out to computers around my campus and we'd like to have stuff put on the taskbar as part of the build. I found a .bat file on this site that was used for a similar question but it seems to be outdated as it only results in multiple errors when I try to run it on my computer.

Comment: I wrote this a few months ago, it's not as easy as I wish it was to do. https://superuser.com/questions/1193985/command-line-code-to-pin-program-to-taskbar-windows-10/1194016#1194016

Answer (score 0):

I found this post: http://joseespitia.com/2016/05/13/how-to-programmatically-pin-icons-in-windows-10, which linked to this program: http://www.technosys.net/products/utils/pintotaskbar.

I personally didn't try it, but it looks credible.

Hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way doing this with plain batch commands, but you can do this by either using VBScript or PowerShell scripts. Both of them are shipped with Windows by default.

Comment: a batch file can create a vbscript and then run it using cscript.exe, so in theory it i spossible.

Comment: @LPChip In fact you are right, but by this argumentation you can also write, compile and execute C++ or any other pl code.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer that does so. ;)