# Can we .bat script 'unpinning' several items from windows taskbar? How about repin?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, taskbar

Can we .bat script 'unpinning' several items from windows taskbar? How about repinning items to the windows taskbar?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: I wrote an answer on this awhile back on how to pin: https://superuser.com/questions/1193985/command-line-code-to-pin-program-to-taskbar-windows-10/1194016#1194016  To remove, you would just remove what you want from the `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\` folder with a bat like ``del %AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\programWantRemoved.xxx``

Answer (score 0):

Yes for now with http://www.technosys.net/products/utils/pintotaskbar - but only for regular software, not apps from Microsoft store