# Pin taskbar icon using VBA in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vba, visual-studio

I have a VBA script that a does a few things before installing a visual studio desktop application. Last line of the VBA script is:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""\\Server\OurApplication\release\setup.exe""")
```

Once this VBA script is run, the application is installed and opens automatically, so the taskbar icon appears in he taskbar. However, because it's not pinned, it disappears as soon as I close the application.

I would like to add a line after this that pins the taskbar icon to the taskbar.

Is there a simple one-liner that can do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command line code to pin program to taskbar Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1193985/command-line-code-to-pin-program-to-taskbar-windows-10)

Comment: Sort of. It suggests it isn't really possible without using some third party tool. However it is 4 years old, so I though there might be some updates since then.